# Sourcing content from a webpage in an organized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to grab different `title` and `address` from different pages of a website. Firstly the script will collect all the property links from the landing page and then go one layer deep to collect the `title` and `address`. When I run my script, I get the results accordingly.

Should it not be a better approach If I call a single function and the rest of the functions work like a chain to produce the same results? If so, what is the right way to do so?

***[This is the link to that site](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGhpiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AEB6AEB-AECkgIBeagCAw;sid=0e2f8c4950c75fa71414020ccd4091ff;class_interval=1&dest_id=102&dest_type=country&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&offset=0&raw_dest_type=country&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&slp_r_match=0&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Ireland&ss_raw=ireland&ssb=empty&sshis=0&)***

Here is the working script:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGhpiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AEB6AEB-AECkgIBeagCAw;sid=7abf6bf275d09e8d4f617d51f4d6c803;class_interval=1;dest_id=102;dest_type=country;dtdisc=0;from_sf=1;group_adults=2;group_children=0;inac=0;index_postcard=0;label_click=undef;no_rooms=1;offset=0;postcard=0;raw_dest_type=country;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;search_selected=1;slp_r_match=0;src=index;src_elem=sb;srpvid=134253d18d97017e;ss=Ireland;ss_all=0;ss_raw=ireland;ssb=empty;sshis=0&'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"}

def get_token():        #getting csrf_token
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one("[name='bhc_csrf_token']")['value']

    payload = {
        'bhc_csrf_token': item,
        'logout': 1
    }
    return payload

def make_post(payload):  #making a post http request with the payload and parsing target page links
    res = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    linklist = []
    for elem in sauce.select(".sr_property_block a.hotel_name_link"):
        linklist.append(urljoin(url,elem.get("href").strip()))
    return linklist

def get_info(link): #scraping title and address by using each of the links
    response = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soupobj = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    name = soupobj.select_one("h2#hp_hotel_name").get_text(strip=True)
    addr = soupobj.select_one(".hp_address_subtitle").get_text(strip=True)
    print(f'{name}\n{addr}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in make_post(get_token()):
        get_info(link)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstand you. But it looks as though you've already written the functions to call one another: `get_info()` calls `make_post()` internally, and `make_post()` then delegates getting the token to `get_token()` by calling it internally to itself. So in your final line of code, you should be able to replace the three calls with a single call to `get_info()`.

Whether or not that's "better" than calling them independently is a question of style. Personally, I think it's best to keep the functions independent and call them separately. This would mean re-writing them to take parameters that are the results of the preceding function call.

This way the functions don't have to know about each other's existence, and means you will be able to change each one independently over time as requirements evolve, without needing to update the others (this is called *low coupling*, a very useful design quality to keep in mind).